# git is not ignoring docker_secrets file even when it is added to .gitignore

Tags: git, docker, gitignore, docker-secrets

```
docker_secrets
```

The above line is in my .gitignore file.

Yet it is still tracking changes to that file.

Answer (score 0):

If it was tracked then you have to remove it from the index:
`git rm --cached <file>`